# How to build a screenmate programmatically?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to build an screenmate.

Something like this:

Example # 1:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHvDOPkGQqE

Example # 2:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tHpmeZseIs

Example # 3:
http://www.viddler.com/explore/myvirtuallady/videos/5/

I guess that there has to be a way to do it, but I don't know how.

Can this be done using some Microsoft frameworks? Maybe with C#?

Comment: I have to do this for a costumer I a don't have any idea of how to build it... on the Web you can find a lot of software to build a screen mate but there has to be an easy way to do this using some Microsoft technologies maybe with the window native manager or something... any ideas????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To draw the screenmate itself you can use a normal Form that has no border and a TransparencyKey color to make the background transparent. You can then draw the animation by overriding OnPaint().

To get it to react to other windows like in the first video is a bit trickier, and requires some pinvoke into user32.dll. The function [FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) gets the handles of other windows and [GetWindowRect](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html) will let you get their position and sizes so you can write some code that makes the screen mate react to them.